# How do I convert (.gif to .png) this image to get the original view?

Tags: conversion, png, gif

I am trying to convert this image, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dijkstra_Animation.gif, to a series of `.png` files.

This was pretty simple, I used the `convert` command in Linux:

```
convert  Dijkstra_Animation.gif dijkstra.png
```

The command went fine and produced the 27 frames, as reported at the bottom of the original page.

However, I find that some of the produced `.png` files are only single numbers or arrows. Which is different from what I expected.

I want the `.png` files to be a simple sequence in the same way the `.gif` file is showing.

Could you please suggest a method *(for Linux please)* to achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using the `-coalesce` option will do the wonder.

Like this,

```
convert -verbose -coalesce Dijkstra_Animation.gif dijkstra.png
```

Actually the `-coalesce` option "merges a sequence of images" as is claimed in the manual page.

Comment: `jalal@klein:~$ convert -verbose -coalesce MRtIA77.gifv rabbit.jpg
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `GIFV' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `rabbit.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.`

Comment: @MonaJalal Are you sure that the name `MRtIA77.gifv` is correct? Perhaps I see an extra `v` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If `convert` does not work for you and you are a Mac user, you can try `sips`, which comes with your MacOS. For example, you can convert a GIF image into a PNG image:

```
sips -s format png 1.gif --out 1.png
```

You can also convert a folder filled with GIFs to PNGs saved in folder pngs:

```
sips -s format png gifs/*.gif --out pngs
```

More about `sips`. It is an abbreviation of Scriptable image processing system. It is used to query or modify raster image files (JPG/GIF/PNG). Image processing options include flip, rotate, change image format/width/height. You can find more details in its manual: in command line `man sips` or at [online manual](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html).

FYI, my MacOS release (obtained by `uname -rsv`) is:

```
Darwin 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Mon Nov 12 20:24:46 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.231.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
```